# Storing list of instances (of self) in class level attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, static, attributes

I have a class in which I would like to store a static reference list of objects of the same class. For example:

```
class Apple:

    NICE_APPLES = [Apple('Elstar', 'Green'), Apple('Braeburn', 'Red'), 
        Apple('Pink Lady', 'Pink')]

    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour
```

This results in a `NameError: name 'Apple' is not defined` error.
Why doesn't this work?

I've changed the code to the following, which seems to work on the console:

```
class Apple:

    NICE_APPLES = []

    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

Apple.NICE_APPLES = [Apple('Elstar', 'Green'), Apple('Braeburn', 'Red'), 
        Apple('Pink Lady', 'Pink')]
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Will this work inside and outside the module, and is this dependent on the way I import the module?

Comment: You can't create an instance of a class until you've finished creating the class! And it doesn't get bound to the name before it's created.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: One potential problem with this approach—regardless of where instances are added to the list—will be maintaining the list when instances are deleted, since there's no mechanism that will automatically remove them. A better way would be to use one of the existing container classes, like lists and dictionaries, or perhaps roll-your-own custom one. Classes should not be concerned with the existence (or non-existence) of instances of themselves. On the other hand, perhaps your instances should be subclasses of `Apple`, in which case there is `class.__subclasses__()` that will keep track of them.

Comment: @ChristianDean I tried to simplify the case with the apple example. What I'm really trying to do is is keep a list of directions (x,y,z offsets) to be able to calculate neigboring cells in a hexagonal grid as seen here: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/implementation.html#hex-distance I guess I could probably just store a list of tuples of names and colours and turn them into apple objects at runtime in a class method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it's true, but it doesn't mean he can do what he is trying to do! look at my answer an you will see

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you explain to me what is wrong with my answer please? maybe I didn't understand something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a classmethod to append apples to your class list.

```
class Apple:

    NICE_APPLES = []

    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

    @classmethod
    def add_nice_apple(cls, name, colour):
        cls.NICE_APPLES.append(cls(name, colour))


Apple.add_nice_apple('Elstar','Green')
Apple.add_nice_apple('Braeburn','Red')
```

Comment: Of course, this way is one of the most cleanest :), plus one

Comment: Indeed! I ended up with storing a list of tuples which I can turn into objects with a method at run time, when needed. If I end up storing them as class instances after all I would use this answer, as I find it the cleanest. Marking this one accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `NICE_APPLES` as an empty list in the Apple class, and then inside `__init__()`, when you're done assigning all the local variables, append `self` to the list.

```
class Apple(object):

    NICE_APPLES = []

    def __init__(self, name, color, keep=False):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

        if keep:
            Apple.NICE_APPLES.append(self)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that create a list of all instances of Apple? I only want a list of a certain set of predefined (hard coded) values.

Comment: Ah.  Well then, you could add an argument to `__init__()` that defaults to `False`, and then only perform the append if that arg is `True`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: @olisch erm, what?  That import statement won't reach inside `my_class_file` and make the `Apple` class forget its real name...

Comment: @JohnGordon plus one! this is a fantastic solution to achieve his goal! thans for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can create new class instance from class method, like this, I think this is a clean way yo do it, and also if you want to store the recent created obj besides a list of hardcords:

```
class Apple:

    NICE_APPLES = []

    def __init__(self, name, colour):
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

    @classmethod
    def init_with_nice_apples(self, name, colour):
        Apple.NICE_APPLES = [Apple('Elstar', 'Green'), Apple('Braeburn', 'Red')] #hardcore list
        self.__init__(self,name, colour)
        Apple.NICE_APPLES.append(self)
        return self

ap = Apple.init_with_nice_apples("Delicius", "Red")
```